# sampling from a CDF only in R?

Tags: r

I have the following function below

I'd like to sample from this CDF (x values) but can't find the inverse function by hand. Is there a way to do it in R?

```
a <- 3.1
be <- -0.15
ga <- 0.78
delt <- 0.12

c<- 3.5

b <- exp(a+be*c*(1+c))
g <- exp((ga+delt*c)*c)


flc_F <- function(x){
  #x between 0 and 1
  if (x<1){
    return ((b*(g-1)*(1-b^x))/(b*(g-1)+(1-b*g)*b^x))
  } else {
    return (1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inverse with `uniroot`:

```r
a <- 3.1
be <- -0.15
ga <- 0.78
delt <- 0.12

c<- 3.5

b <- exp(a+be*c*(1+c))
g <- exp((ga+delt*c)*c)


flc_F <- function(x){
  #x between 0 and 1
  if (x<1){
    return ((b*(g-1)*(1-b^x))/(b*(g-1)+(1-b*g)*b^x))
  } else {
    return (1)
  }
}
flc_F <- Vectorize(flc_F)

# Quantile function
Qflc_F <- function(p){
  sapply(p, function(.x) uniroot(
        function(p) flc_F(p) - .x, 
        interval = c(0, 1e16) 
  )[["root"]])
}
```

Plot of the functions. CDF...

```
curve(flc_F(x), from = 0, to = 1)
```

[image]

And Inverse (that is, Quantile function:

```r
curve(Qflc_F(x), from = 0.1, to = 0.99)
```

[image]

PD: Note two things:
1 - I vectorized your original function using Vectorize(), thus you can use it with vectors (there are possibly more efficient ways though)
2 - I set a limit for search the root in `uniroot` between 0 and 1e16, of course that function could be refined to treat Inf values in better way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you have the cdf, You can use the `inverse cdf` method to sample from the density:

```
a <- 3.1
be <- -0.15
ga <- 0.78
delt <- 0.12

c<- 3.5

b <- exp(a+be*c*(1+c))
g <- exp((ga+delt*c)*c)


flc_F <- function(x){
  #x between 0 and 1
  if(x<0) return(NA)
  if (x<1){
    return ((b*(g-1)*(1-b^x))/(b*(g-1)+(1-b*g)*b^x))
  } else {
    return (1)
  }
}

# Inverse of the cdf:

flc_Inv <- function(x)optimise(\(y)(flc_F(y)-x)^2,c(0,1) )[[1]]
```

Now just sample points from `uniform(0,1)` and invert them to follow the said distribution using the inverse cdf function:

```
 pnts <- runif(10000) 
 new_pnts <- sapply(pnts, flc_Inv)
```

Now you can use the function below to sample:

```
 r_flc <- function(n) sapply(runif(n), flc_Inv)
 hist(r_flc(10000))
```

[image]